# Analysis of .inject vs .each_with_object

Tags: ruby

I know that  `each_with_object` does not work on immutable objects like `integer`.

For example `(1..3).each_with_object(0) {|i,sum| sum += i} #=> 0`

We can fix this with inject, and the sum will be `6`. Great!

Lets take another example

```
("a".."c").each_with_object("") {|i,str| str += i} # => ""
```

This won't work either since when we do `str+=i`, we make a new object

Instead we need to do

```
("a".."c").each_with_object("") {|i,str| str << i} # => "abc"
```

Why is it that when I do `inject` in the following two ways I get weird results

```
("a".."c").inject("") {|i,str| str += i} # => cba

("a".."c").inject("") {|i,str| str << i} # => ERROR
```

Why is the first printing `abc` in reverse? And why is the second an error?

I know that we should use `.each_with_object` for mutable objects, and `inject` for immutable (like `Integer`), but can I use 
`.inject` for mutable objects as well just like `.each_with_object`? Can anyone explain these results?

Comment: You can also write `("a".."c").each_with_object("") { |s,str| str.replace(str+s) } #=> "abc"`. Note I used `s` (for "string", or I might have used `c` for "char") as the block variable `i` normally represents an index. I'm not aware of a situation where `each_with_object` cannot be replaced by `inject`, but cannot offer a proof of that assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the first printing abc in reverse?

***The arguments are backwards.*** See [Enumerable#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Printing `i` and `str` shows the problem.

```
$ ruby -e '("a".."c").inject("") {|i,str| puts "i   = #{i}"; puts "str = #{str}"; ret = str += i; puts "ret = #{ret}\n\n"; ret }'
i   = 
str = a
ret = a

i   = a
str = b
ret = ba

i   = ba
str = c
ret = cba
```

`i` is the accumulated sum returned the last time through the block. `str` is the next value. You're adding the previous accumulated value to then end of the next one. You have the arguments backwards. The first one is the sum, the second is the next element.

When that's corrected it works fine.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ("a".."c").inject("") {|sum,i| sum += i}'
abc
```

Furthermore, ***it's the return value of the block that's used***. Altering `str` has no effect, it just confuses things further.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ("a".."c").inject("") {|sum,i| sum + i}'
abc
```

> And why is the second an error?

It isn't, not in Ruby 2.0.0 nor 2.2.4 anyway. But it has the same problem of backwards args.

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ("a".."c").inject("") {|i,str| str << i} # => ERROR'
cba

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Comment: So then `.inject` can replace `each_with_object`, in all cases? Is there a case `.each_with_object` can be used that inject can't?

Comment: @bill `each_with_object` does not care about the return value from the block which is nice to not have to make sure you are always returning the correct object. e.g. `("a".."c").each_with_object({}) {|e,obj| obj[e] = e.next}` the return value first look would actually be "b" which would be very different with inject `("a".."c").inject({}) {|obj,e| obj[e] = e.next}`. this would have to change to `("a".."c").inject({}) {|e,obj| obj[e] = e.next;obj}`

Comment: @engineersmnky, can you explain whats going on in both of those examples, I dont really understand

Comment: Ohh I see so inject just returns the block value, while each_with_object wil return obj. By the way  `("a".."c").inject({}) {|e,obj| obj[e] = e.next;obj}`, doesent work in irb

Comment: @bill yes typo it would be `("a".."c").inject({}) {|obj,e| obj[e] = e.next;obj}` i forgot to reverse the piped parameters by accident when copying the `each_with_object` implementation